# A module to limit number of posts a user can make during a set period of time?

Tags: 7, advertising

I have a number of sites that allows users to post nodes and comments, however bots are getting a hold of these and having their way with my site. I recall seeing a module a while back (but cannot remember it's name) that allows admins to set a time limit between posts. Basically denying posts that made within minutes or seconds of eachother. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Node limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit) module can help? I haven't used it but it seems that this may be what you need.

Comment: Node limit dropped support for "Per time-frame node limits" unfortunately. The [Node Limit Number](http://drupal.org/project/node_limitnumber) module has that functionality, but doesn't have a Drupal 7 release as yet

Comment: Node Limit does still contain the Node Limit Interval submodule.

Answer (score 2):

[Honeypot](http://drupal.org/project/honeypot) seems to be your solution. I discovered it after i used mollom but it seems very useful.

Honeypot uses both the honeypot and timestamp methods of deterring spam bots from completing forms on your Drupal site (read more here). These methods are effective against many spam bots, and are not as intrusive as CAPTCHAs or other methods which punish the user

Comment: The Honeypot timestamp method disables caching, so I will not go with this method. ALthough it is a relevant approach to this issue (upvoted).